# <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>

Tags: html

I'm using react-router-dom's Link like

```
<Link to="link1">
  ...
  <Link to "link2"> ... </Link>
  ...
  <Link to "link3"> ... </Link>
  ...
</Link>
```

but I -logically- get the warning : validateDOMNesting(...): <a> cannot appear as a descendant of <a>.

any alternatives ? or I just need to ignore that ?

EDIT :

[image]

It is that all the row is supposed to be clickable and take to the profile page, and the other buttons one is for deleting and the other for blocking a user.
I can click the button inside but the parent (row) gets clicked aswell (both in one click), and that's after setting the "onClick" in the insider buttons.

Comment: Why are you trying to put a link in a link to start with?!

Comment: You can't have a link inside a link. If you click a link you get redirected to the page you clicked on. But what if you have a link inside a link, where do you expect to be redirected? link 1 or link 2? or first link 1 then link 2? or link 2 then link 1? it doesn't make any sense, so don't put links inside links.

Comment: please don't do this :) there is a reason why it's warning you and it's a bad idea to ignore. keep links separately

Comment: the matter is that I have a big div which should be all clickable, and inside that div I have 3 other icons, each of them should clickable aswell, each of them has a link
Actually it works as wanted, I'm just worried about the warning !

Answer (score -1):

An alternative will be onClick event and changing the elements to components instead of using `<Link> in <Link>`